# MySQL: How to get the last message of conversation between two users?

Tags: mysql

This is what my database looks like

```
id | Sender  |  Receiver |  Send_Date   | Message
=========================================================
1  | user A  |   user B  |  1463311906 | hello
2  | user B  |   user A  |  1463311906 | hi
3  | user A  |   user B  |  1463311906 | howdy
4  | user C  |   user A  |  1463311906 | great
5  | user A  |   user C  |  1463311906 | good
```

I want to select the last message of conversation between two different users. For example, a list where it shows the last message between user A and B, last message between user B and C and so on, where user B or C is not defined. The user A is the user using the application and he wants to see last message of his conversation with all other users (B, C etc), either be the last message is his or from the opposite user.

So far I've tried with the below query, but this shows both the last messages sent by user A and User B in a conversation between user A and user B, it's the same with User A and C, when I only want the last messages sent or received between these users.

```
SELECT send_date
     , message
     , reciever
     , sender 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM messages 
        WHERE sender = user A or reciever = user A
     ) AS newmesssages 
 GROUP 
    BY sender
     , reciever 
 ORDER 
    BY send_date DESC
```

Comment: You are missing some information in your inner select. Logically, the question you want answered is:

For the pair A and B, where A is either the sender or the receiver, and B is either the receiver or the sender, and A = :FrontUser or B = :FrontUser, get the message info with the latest timestamp.

Comment: Some more information would be useful as well. For example, where does `:frontUser` get set, or passed from? A stored procedure will be easiest, because the logic of pairing, alongside the existing table-structure, makes it difficult to do in a straight `sql` query.

Comment: No pictures, thanks. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and only include relevant columns

Comment: Incidentally, it's 'rec*ei*ver'

Comment: I've updated the question. I guess what I'm trying to get is impossible without adding an additional row, "conversation ID"

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT send_date, message, receiver, sender
FROM messages
WHERE (sender = :userA AND reciever = :userB) OR (sender = :userB AND reciever = :userA)
ORDER BY send_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If User A sends a message to User B, and then User B sends a message to User C, the above script will happily exclude the A-B conversation and report on the B-C one, when we run the query with `frontUser == B`. Assuming one message per conversation.

Comment: You right, `WHERE` condition need to be more strict.

Comment: I guess my question was poorly explained. User B is not defined. The user A is the user using the application and he wants to see last message of his conversation with all other users, either be the last message is his or the opposite user.

Comment: Then your condition should be just fine `WHERE sender = user A or reciever = user A`. You already have `ORDER BY send_date DESC` so the latest `send_date` will be on top of results you just need to add `LIMIT 1` to pick up first row from results. `GROUP BY` and sub-query does not make any sense in this case.